# sending variable from one jsp to another jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session, servlets

I have one JSP file as **jsp 1.jsp**
and another JSP file as **jsp 2.jsp**

I've included **jsp 2.jsp** in **jsp 1.jsp** using `<%@include file="jsp 2.jsp" %>`

Now I need a click event on some element. And on that event I want to transfer a string variable to included jsp.

Lets say I have a list and on click of it I want to transfer the name of the list to another JSP,

And in another JSP I am trying to use that string to carry out some task.

And I am doing all these without any servlet.
challenging one!!
I have google'd a lot, but didnt find anything.

Comment: put a hidden field <input type="hidden" display="none" value="<Your own custom value goes here>" name="stringVar">. You will get this value on server side with request.getParameter("stringVar");

Comment: @KrsnaChaitanya can you explain it more...thanksss... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a number of options:

1. Store it in the session.

   ```
   // Memorise any passed in user.
   String username = request.getParameter("username");
   if (username != null && username.length() > 0) {
     session.setAttribute("username", username);
   }
   ```
2. Store it as a hidden field in the form.

   ```
   <input name="username" type="hidden" value=""/>
   ```
3. Store it in a cookie.

   ```
   username = getCookie(userCookieName);

   // Get from cookie.
   function getCookie(name) {
     if (document.cookie) {
       index = document.cookie.indexOf(name);
       if (index !== -1) {
         f = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
         t = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
         if (t === -1) {
           t = document.cookie.length;
         }
         return(document.cookie.substring(f, t));
       }
     }
     return ("");
   }
   ```
4. Persist it on the client side in sessionStorage. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) for details.

   ```
   sessionStorage.setItem("username", "...");
   ```
5. Not really another option but a mechanism - pass it in the URL:

   ```
   .... onclick="window.location='details.jsp?username=...'
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If the reason for including your `jsp 2` in `jsp 1` is for sending variable, then its `not needed`.
you just need to set a `hidden` variable in `jsp 1`, and in your `jsp 2` you should able to access it, by using the `jsp implicit request` object.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Ajax with JQuery` to achieve your goal or you can simply store the String object in `session` and you can delete it in `jsp2.jsp` when ever you use it. or you can simply append to a `url` as `query string` there are multiple ways among them the above are few.

These questions may help you

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350674/passing-variables-with-post-to-another-page-with-jquery)

[Question 2](http://www.java-forums.org/javaserver-pages-jsp-jstl/29681-how-pass-parameter-one-jsp-another-jsp.html)

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052647/pass-value-to-another-jsp)

[Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0):

in jsp1
use this way to pass value.

```
<form action="">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="hidden">
<input type="submit" value="submit"></form>
```

in jsp2 to get value

```
String value=request.getParameter("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `jsp:param`, as in this example [jsp:param element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnajd/index.html) or take a look at this similar post [Passing parameters between JSP pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141674/jsp-passing-parameters-between-jsp-pages).