# Send value from 1 jsp to another jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have 1 JSP, say `1.jsp` in which I have a value which am getting from `request.getAttribute("testvalue")` from action class, as I am using Struts framework. I need to send  this value from `1.jsp` to another `2.jsp`. Please let me know how  to do this?

Also going ahead,i need to send this value from `2.jsp` to `3.jsp`.
Am trying to avoid using setting the value in session.
So let me know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? I did, and there are a ton of answers, many from SO.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763168/sending-variable-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting value from the request, you should be putting a value to a request. This code

```
request.getAttribute("testvalue");
```

is getting a value, but that code

```
request.setAttribute("testvalue", value);
```

is putting it.

This is because you want to avoid using the HTTP session.

Answer (score 0):

If this is within a single request, the request attributes are available to all pages in the forwarding chain.  This means all servlets and JSP's have access.  So at any point during the request cycle, *after* the attribute has been set, the value can be retrieved using request.getAttribute(String).

Answer (score 0):

Here are 4 another way that i know:

use get Parameter:for example you have a link to second jsp file. add your parameter at the end of your link. like this: `mysite.com/second.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2`

use form in the firstjsp page and in this use hidden input:

```
<form action="second.jsp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1" />
<input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value2" />
<input type="submit" name="next" value="Next Page" />
</form>
```

use application variable but if your data is general for all, or use speciall param name for store your value. for example you can use:

```
<% application.setAttribute("user1_param1","value1"); %>
```

use RequestDispatcher in your code. and set your param in the request object instead of session.

```
<%
request.setAttribute("param1","value1");
RequestDispatcher r=request.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp");
r.forward(request, response);
%>
```

please Subtilize that you can use each other in the different state. for example you can use RequestDispatcher when you will forward a request before send any result ro user. and the other ways use when you will your current data back to you in the second page in the next use request.