# Transfer variable value from 1 jsp page to another jsp age

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am using MYSQL database and for programming I am using JSP. Now I am extracting a value from database in my result.jsp page using this code:

```
String pid="";
while(resultSet.next()
{
<form action="report.jsp">
<%=resultSet.getString("patient_id") %>
<% pid=resultSet.getString("patient_id"); %>
<% request.setAttribute("acId", "pid"); %> 
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
}
```

pid is a variable used to store the value of Patient ID.

I want to transfer that value to another jsp page which is report.jsp

I am retrieving the value in repost.jsp as follows:

```
<%
String paid = (String)(request.getAttribute("acId"));
%>
```

Then I have to store this value in database. But no value is being tranferred and stored in the variable paid.

I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713016/send-value-from-1-jsp-to-another-jsp) but got no help.

Please ignore any errors as I am new to MYSQL and JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<% request.setAttribute("acId", "pid"); %>
```

Use

```
<input id="acId" name="acId" type="hidden" value="<%= pid %>" />
```

So that when submitting, every form input element will be transferred to the report.jsp.

And btw: you 're using while(resultSet.next())...may better to use if(resultSet.next())