# how to pass dropdown selected value from one jsp to another in springs

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have two jsp pages in my spring project. In first jsp I have one dynamic dropdown list and one link tag which directs to second jsp page. I want to pass the selected item of dropdown list to second jsp. So how can I pass parameter as selected value in href and how can I get the value in second jsp.

```
<form:select id="Id" path="Id">
        <form:options items="${IdList}">
    </form:select>

    <a href="<%=basepath%>secondpage"> Second Page </a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending variable from one jsp to another jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763168/sending-variable-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Because u want to pass it via the a tag, href attribute, add a onchange handler on your select tag, then at that handler modify the href attribute of the second page link. You should use javascript.