# how to use variable of one JSP to othe JSP

Tags: jsp

1.I have two jsp program let abc1.jsp and abc2.jsp
2.abc1.jsp use some variable(let var a1,a2,a3)
3.run abc1.jsp for get the variabe value
3.need the value of same variable(a1,a2,a3) for abc2.jsp
how I do this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: [repeat Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763168/sending-variable-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sessions for this.
Here is an example.

the html page-

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="SaveName.jsp">
What's your name? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=username SIZE=20>
<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

SaveName.jsp -

```
<%
   String name = request.getParameter( "username" );
   session.setAttribute( "theName", name );
%>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<A HREF="NextPage.jsp">Continue</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

NextPage.jsp -

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello, <%= session.getAttribute( "theName" ) %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string for this in following way :

You can use a1,a2,a3 in abc2.jsp by using the querystring.

send these variable in query string and get that variable values in another page.

```
page1.jsp

<form action="page2.jsp?v1=<%=a1%>&v2=<%=a2%>">
</form>

page2.jsp
String var1=request.getParameter("v1");
String var2=request.getParameter("v2");
```

Comment: There are some error.An error occurred at line: 105 in the jsp file: /NewFile.jsp
a4 cannot be resolved to a variable
102: 
103: }
104: 
105: <form action="NewFile1.jsp?v1=<%=a3%>&v2=<%=a4%>">
106: </form>
107: 
108: function myFunctio() Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:451)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)