# How to pass an Object from one JSP to other JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have two jsp files, jsp1 and jsp2. When an edit button clicked on jsp1 will call a java script function . From javascript function i am calling jsp2. I used window.open beacuse i need this jsp2 as opens as a popup.Now i want to pass an object from jsp1 to jsp2 when i click edit button.How can i do that?.

```
    This is my code

    jsp1

    < script language="JavaScript">

            function edit(){

                    window.open("jsp2.jsp",'popuppage',"height=600,width=800,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
                    return true;

                }
    < /script>

     < stripes:form name="upload"
                        action="/upload.action" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          < table>

         <% List<TableDto> list = (List<TableDto>)request.getAttribute("table"); %>

                            <%
                                if(list != null){
                                 for (TableDto dto : list) { 
                            %>
                      < tr>
                                <td><%=dto.getName()%></td>
                                <td><img src="<%=dto.getPath() %>" width="40px"
                                    height="40px" /></td>
                                <td><%=dto.getText()%></td>
                                <td>


                                <input type="image" name="edit"onclick="edit()"
                                    src="${globalPath}/images/edit_pen.jpg">

                    < /tr>

                            <%
                                } 
                                }
                            %>

          </table>
    < /stripes:form>
```

Comment: You can try to use `postMessage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage or add get parameter `window.open("jsp2.jsp?foo=bar",...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763168/sending-variable-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp

Comment: @FrederikWitte it's different question because it use `include` to load second file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.use url parameters
You can add url parameters such as "jsp2?xxx=xxx&xxx=xxx". Then in controller(jsp2), you can get these parameters by

```
request.getParameter("xx")
```

and pass variables to jsp engine.

2.use cookies
You can write js code to save data in cookies and then read data in jsp2

```
///write cookies
document.cookie="xx="+xx;
///read cookies
function getCookie(name)
{
    var arr,reg=new RegExp("(^| )"+name+"=([^;]*)(;|$)");
    if(arr=document.cookie.match(reg))
        return unescape(arr[2]);
    else
        return null;
}
```

3.use session
In controller1(jsp1), save session by

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(name, value);
```

In jsp2, read session by

```
request.getSession().getAttribute(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use

- If you are using forward (jsp:foprward or RequestDispatcher) from one page to another, then use **request.setAttribute(..) and request.getAttribute(), because you are within the same request**
- If you are using redirect (via response.sendRedirect()), then use **request.getSession().setAttribute(..) and request.getSession().getAttribute().**

Answer (score 0):

Below are ways to pass values from one page to another page -

1. Putting values into the session object.
2. Putting values into the application object
3. Putting values at the end of the redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

The following sample works for me. The first page contains handler function:

```
function popup() {
    window.data = {name : 'myName'};
    var handle = window.open('importJSON.html', 'popup',"height=600,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
}
```

The second page contains handler function:

```
function showName2() {
    alert(window.opener ? window.opener.data.name : undefined);
}
```

Tested on Chromium 47 and Firefox 43. It doesn't throws exception *'Blocked a frame with origin "null"... Protocols, domains, and ports must match'* if both pages opened from the same host. It looks to me better not to send a data object through a network back and forth if it is possible not to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the object in an attribute which you can store in the session and in the other jsp , you can retrieve from the session and use.

Comment: could you please say, where i set the Object in attribute?

Comment: Check the answer from Jenkin Zhou