# How to pass an integer value from one jsp page to other jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

i have two file abc.jsp & def.jsp. in abc.jsp, it contains this code:

```
<%
        String selectedCourse = request.getParameter("course");
        int count = 0;

        if(selectedCourse.equals("PHP")){
            count = count + 1;
        }

    %>
```

i want this count value in def.jsp, so how can i pass this value?

Comment: Check this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763168/sending-variable-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp

Comment: i want to pass integer, i can pass string, but can't pass integer!

Comment: Exactly the same way, just use `Integer` and not `int` (i.e. object, not the primitive type).

Comment: i don't get it :/ can u explain with this code pls?

Comment: Everytime you come to `abc.jsp` page you intialize your count to `0` , So previous value it has in it will get lost .Try to store `count` in `session` and retreive count from `session` and then add it with `1` , also has `count` is already in session you can get that in any page i.e by writing `int count = session.getAttribute("count"); ` .

Answer (score 1):

abc.jsp

```
<%!
private synchronized void incrementCounter() {
  Integer count = session.getAttribute("count");
  if (count == null) {
    count = new Integer(0);
  }
  count++;
  session.setAttribute("count", new Integer(count));
}
%>

<%
String selectedCourse = request.getParameter("course");
if(selectedCourse.equals("PHP")){
  incrementCounter();
}
%>
```

def.jsp

```
<%
int count = session.getAttribute("count"); 
%>
```

Anyway, such logic should not be in JSP, but belongs into a controller (servlet).

Answer (score 0):

Use Session Attributes

abc.jsp

```
<%
    String selectedCourse = request.getParameter("course");
    int count = 0;

    if(selectedCourse.equals("PHP")){
        count = count + 1;
    }
     session.setAttribute("count", count);
%>
```

def.jsp

```
int count1 = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("count").toString());

out.write("count:"+count1);
```

Comment: not working, getting the initialize value of count 0 always!

Comment: int  count1 = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("count").toString());

    out.write("count:"+count1);

Comment: int count1 = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("count").toString()); is not working, it catches nullPointerException after running!